# SpriteKit - Show a loading screen as game initializes in the background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch

There's noticeable lag between my main menu and my game scene. How can I run all my initialization code in `didMove(to view: SKView)` while displaying some sort of loading screen, and then after it's finished, present the game? I don't really need code as an answer but more so as a structure or approach I can use.

What I'm guessing I would do is have my normal transition from menu to game scene, present some sort of loading image in my game scene while running the initialization code in a background thread? Then I would need some way to check when that background thread has finished running so I can remove the loading image and present the game.

Does this sound correct? Also what should I be looking into to perform the initialization in the background and check if it has finished?

MenuScene:

```
 // nextScene is GameScene here
self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0))
```

GameScene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

   // A whole lot of initialization code that causes lag before the user can start interacting with the game

}
```

What I wanna do:

GameScene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

   // Present Loading Screen

   // Do initialization in a background thread
   // Once it's done, remove loading screen

}
```

Comment: You might want to show *your* structure.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth edited my question but it's really just a standard structure for SpriteKit with my initialization code in didMove(to view: ) with an SKTransition

Comment: initialization should have already happened by the time you hit `didMove(to view:SKView)`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I wasn't aware that there was a sceneDidLoad() function, I moved my initialization code to that function and now there is visibly less lag.